# Strange Behaviour of Yii CGridView with large number of columns - Ajax URLs are messed up

Tags: php, ajax, url, yii

I have recently started to work with Yii and have been quite impressed with it. However, i am facing a strange issue with regards to how Ajax URLs are created for CGridView. What i am trying is searching for the first time, then going some pages ahead in the search results by clicking on the pagination links and then searching again. However the second time my grid is sending request in the following format

```
http://127.0.0.1/myapp/backend/customers/index/XDEBUG_SESSION_START/1/Accounts%5BaccountID%5D//Accounts%5Bname%5D//Accounts%5Baddress%5D/address+1/Accounts%5Bbirthday%5D//Accounts%5BclientType%5D//Accounts%5Bemail%5D//Accounts%5Bbalance%5D//Accounts%5BhasAccess%5D//Accounts_page/3/ajax/yw1?ajax=yw1&Accounts%5BaccountID%5D=&Accounts%5Bname%5D=&Accounts%5Baddress%5D=&Accounts%5Bbirthday%5D=&Accounts%5BclientType%5D=&Accounts%5Bemail%5D=&Accounts%5Bbalance%5D=&Accounts%5BhasAccess%5D=&Accounts_page=1
```

you can see half of this URL is Re-written (which is created by CPagination when rendering pagination links). However, Yii's gridview js appends the new query to pagination link ending up with duplication of variables in URL with both previous and new value. As a result of this, when the code execution reaches Line 411 in the CUrlManager.php which is

```
$_REQUEST[$name]=$_GET[$name]=$value;
```

the value in $_GET variable are lost ($value contain old values of the url which are contained in the rewritten part of the URL (SEO Friendly)). And I end up with previous search results again.

The Rules that i am using

```
 'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>"=>"<module>/<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => true,
        ),
```

search function in model

```
  */
    public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('accountID', $this->accountID, true);
        $criteria->compare('name', $this->name, true);
        $criteria->compare('balance', $this->balance, true);
        $criteria->compare('address', $this->address, true);
        $criteria->compare('birthday', $this->birthday, true);
        $criteria->compare('clientType', $this->clientType, true);
        $criteria->compare('email', $this->email, true);
        $criteria->compare('createAt', $this->createAt, true);
        $criteria->compare('hasAccess', $this->hasAccess);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                    'criteria' => $criteria,
                ));
    }
```

behaviours in model

```
    public function behaviors() {
    return array('CAdvancedArBehavior' => array(
            'class' => 'application.extensions.CAdvancedArBehavior'));
}
```

actionIndex Code

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['attribute']))
        {

            $attribute =$_POST['attribute'];
            $attribute = @explode('_',$attribute);

                $row = Accounts::model()->findByPk($attribute[1]);
                if($row != null )
                {

                                $row->save();

                }




        $dataProvider= new Accounts('search');
                $dataProvider->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Accounts']))
            $dataProvider->attributes=$_GET['Accounts'];

            $this->render('index', array('model' => $dataProvider));
    }

 }
```

My view file :

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
       'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
            array (
                'name' => 'accountID',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')

            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'address',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')

            ),

            array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
            'name'=>'birthday',
            'value'=>'date("M j, Y", strtotime($data->birthday))',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')
            ),

             array(
                'name' => 'clientType',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')

            ),

            array(
                'name' => 'email',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')

            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'balance',
                'type' => 'raw',
                'header' => 'Balance',
                'value' =>'($this->grid->owner->widget("application.extensions.jeditable.DsJEditableWidget", array(
                 "model" => $this->grid->dataProvider,
                 "name" => "balance_".$data->accountID,
                 "value" => $data->balance,
                 "jeditable_type" => "text",
                ),true))',
            ),

            array(            // 
                'class' => 'JToggleColumn',
                'name' => 'hasAccess',
                'filter' => array(1=>'Yes', 0=>'No'),
                'checkedButtonImageUrl'=> Yii::App()->baseUrl.'/images/checked.png', // checked image
                'uncheckedButtonImageUrl'=> Yii::App()->baseUrl.'/images/unchecked.png', // unchecked image
                'checkedButtonLabel'=>'Yes', // tooltip
                'uncheckedButtonLabel'=>'No', // tooltip
                'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;min-width:60px;')
            ),
        )

    )
```

I dont want to use

```
'ajaxUrl' => $this->createUrl('index')
```

as it resets my search and pagination when i try to use jtogglecolumn, due to absence of query data in request url.

Comment: Please post the dataProvider code.

Comment: Before the render of the grid you could try using unset on $_GET.

Comment: would that not lose the current page number as well resulting in resetting of pagination as well as search filter each time? can you elaborate a bit Alex. And can you also comment if you are able to replicate this behavior. I am using Yii 1.1.10

Comment: On some early Yii projects I had the same issue, unset-ing the variables in $_GET stops them getting added to the url.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and after much playing around found that my Nginx config was wrong. Hope this helps someone

**Nginx.conf**

```
location / {

        index  index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri;    #Use the default config as above

    }
```